# Get a position of element inside of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm really struggling with presenting a popover from a button inside of **UITableViewCell**

When I handle **button.TouchUpInside** event, **((UIButton)sender).Frame** is always the same value - the position is relative to the cell not to the current view, which results in the wrong location for the popover. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why I had some much trouble with this, but this worked:

`var location = button.ConvertRectToView(button.Bounds, View);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the offset that is applied by the table view. `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, which has a [contentOffsett](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property. Add this to your frame to find the real location.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try that, I was hoping to get the correct location without having to store and reference UITableView itself

Comment: You can always navigate up the view hierarchy via the supervise property

Answer (score 0):

`((UIButton)sender).bounds`

will return you your required value

Comment: Hm, no that doesn't seem to work. Returns (0,0) for position and correct height/width